# How to move a continent?

Tags: terraforming

In the future, the world is suffering from overpopulation. Scientific advancement has made Antarctica tolerable (think more like northern Alaska), but it's still petty useless land, so most of it is unused. The Martian Terraformers Guild has agreed to use their special and secret knowledge to move Antarctica northward.

Anyone know how? How long does it take? What are the side effects and limitations?

Comment: How to move a continent?  One stone at a time.

Comment: Doesn't the Antarctica melt if you move it northward?

Comment: Maybe think of raising the pacific plate instead of moving another plate.

Comment: How is Antarctica tolerable, but useless?  And by deliberately melting the southern icecap, you just wiped out a majority of major population centers on the planet.

Comment: The Antarctic plate is drifting away from the South Pole all by itself, progressing about 1 cm per year roughly in the direction of the Indian Ocean. Current estimations are that in 50 to 75 million years it will have moved sufficiently far for the Antarctic continent to be mostly free of ice. (It will also break into two parts, but that's of secondary importance.)

Comment: Easier to just create more land by flattening mountains and putting the extra earth in the sea than to move a continent.

Comment: @a.c.a.c They have already taken such relatively simple measures.

Comment: @A. C. A. C.: Easier still just to implement birth control.  If people won't do it voluntarily, just genetically engineer a virus.  But of course, if global warming has gotten to the point where the Antarctic ice cap has melted, the resulting environmental problems will render humans extinct, along with most other higher life forms, so the problem solved itself without need for expensive planetary remodelling :-)

Comment: Much easier to build habitable greenhouse domes on Antarctica, than to try and move an entire continent.

Answer (score 6):

Like the pieces of a puzzle, you cannot move a continent without rearranging all the others. If you move Antarctica north, you have to move something else south to fill the gap.

In principle it is doable (it happens already over billion of years at a slow pace) thanks to the fact that all the continents float on the mantle. You only need a suitable force to pull/push the continents, the only problem is that it will increase the stresses on the crust and therefore induce earthquakes.

Earthquakes aside, you are also moving a large mass from the pole to somewhere north, thus you are also changing the moment of inertia of the planet. You will end up slowing down the rotation (you are moving mass far from the axis of rotation) and very likely you will also modify the orientation of the rotation axis itself, as it depends on the mass distribution.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case. As you rightly say "all the continents float on the mantel". This means, among other things, that moving a continent in one place dislodges a corresponding amount of mantel. The two things don't exactly compensate, but resulting net effect would be very small, probably too small to be noticed at all.

Comment: @ZioByte, I remember reading somewhere that all the huge dams recently built have measurably altered the length of the day, since they changed the geoid momentum of inertia. And a dam is way smaller and thinner than a continent.

Answer (score 5):

## In no world bound by the laws of logic would anyone do this. Ever.

First of all, Antarctica is not, in fact, land. It is many hundreds of meters of ice frozen over an archipelago, so this probably explains why the land is useless. The moment you move it to the vast lands of not-the-bottom-of-the-world, you melt ***ALL*** of that ice (well perhaps not the *very* moment, but you get the idea), sending many trillions of gallons of water into the sea,  ***completely submerging more land than you would create***.

Secondly, with the energy it would take to move the continent 100 miles, you could just as easily send the entire human population into space. If you really want to warm Antarctica, just use space mirrors to concentrate solar energy onto the continent. It would still be a waste of energy, but a much more *efficient* waste of energy

Answer (score 1):

**The Martian Terraforming Guild are master frackers.**

Obviously, plates move faster during earthquakes.  Stresses build up and when finally released, a lot of accumulated energy is expended quickly.  Plates wind up in their new positions, and stresses once against start to build.

Deep injection of fluids, as is done during "fracking" or deep earth disposal wells, can lubricate friction spots between plates, allowing slippage.

From https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/drilling-for-earthquakes/
[image: schematic of how fracking causes earthquakes]

This process may happen naturally as well: naturally occurring fluids move into tight spaces and lubricate the movement of plates between each other.

https://www.livescience.com/46386-what-causes-slow-slip-earthquakes.html

> Slow earthquakes unleash the same amount of seismic energy as regular
>   earthquakes, but because the fault movements last for minutes to
>   months, they cause no damaging shaking. These sluggish quakes also
>   originate deeper on the fault than where faster temblors tend to
>   strike. Scientists aren't sure if slow earthquakes can trigger deadly
>   fast quakes, but many researchers are investigating the link between
>   the two kinds of earthquakes

The Martians grok exactly how and where to inject specific lubricating fluids to allow rapid and gradual movement of plates.  This accelerates plate tectonics and, so continental movement, speeding Antarctica north for its rendezvous with South America.  Gradual movement of the plates is much less dramatic and potentially catastrophic than the current, high friction system the Earth has.  The next and obvious step is to apply Martian lubricating techniques to all of Earths continental plates, allowing them to move freely and easily about.

.

Comment: This would not work. In the time you could "gradually" move plates how you wanted you could more easily fix the Earth's climate. Let alone this process does not control the direction of the moving plate only lubricating the contact between them. The real problem is moving a plate, or section of, in any kind of human  worthwhile time frame (even millenia) would cause earthquakes, volcanoes, and tidal waves at the magnitudes of extinction level events.

Answer (score 1):

**No this is not in the realm of scientifically possible**

**First**, A continent isn't simply a lump of rock above an ocean. Even though that's essentially how it's defined.

Ever wonder why Mars doesn't have continents? A continent is a significant grouping of tectonic plates. Imagine a sea of lava with huge rocks floating on its surface. That sea of lava is the Earth's mantle and those rocks are tectonic plates that make the Earth's crust. Mars doesnt have continents because its mantle is dead so there are no plates to conglomerate continents and no Oceans to divide land masses into the groupings of continents.

Now,
You can't budge a tectonic plate without causing huge earthquakes. You cant overlap plates (this is called subduction and results in shoving crust into the mantle [sea of lava]).You can't lift a plate over another, causes volcanoes and new crust to form as well as a cataclysmic event (basaltic eruption) .

**What you could do:**
You could drill holes through the crust to the mantle to form volcanoes in the ocean bed which would create new land.This is far more sane/plausible than moving a plate.

**Or** you could do it the current way and just dump tons of material in the ocean to form islands. China has been doing this a lot recently to expand their territory in the South China Sea. (dredging)